# How to get a specific datasources from Grafana API without knowing the id?

Tags: datasource, grafana

I use the Grafana API to create a lot of datasources (dynamically) so I don't know their ID. Now I want to delete a specific datasources from the API so the method is:

1. Get the specific datasource
2. Take the id from the response
3. Delete this datasource

But I can only search all datasources because I don't know the ID and then I'll need to iterate over each datasources and search the one with the same name + ip ? there is no other solution ?
http://docs.grafana.org/reference/http_api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have an old docs page.. How did you find that? I want to make sure it goes away :)

The new http [docs](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/data_source/) contains an api endpoint for getting datasource by name.

You can also delete datasource by name

`DELETE /api/datasources/name/:datasourceName`

But we currently do not support deleting by ip + name

Comment: I founded it by typing "Grafana datasources api" and it was ones of the first link. So it's perfect if we can delete by name ! thank you really much !

And it's right the name is unique ? We can't have 2 datasource_A right ?

Comment: Correct. Datasource names have to be unique. Thanks for the info about how you found the page :)